# vue jest Como testear que al ocurrir un evento input se llame a un metodo dentro de un componente

Tags: vue.js, test, jest

Estoy tratando de testear un input de tipo email que al ocurrir el evento input llama a un metodo updateDni. Mi template es el siguiente:

```
<template>
<v-text-field
    color="orange"
    hide-details
    label="DNI"
    outlined
    type="string"
    :value="dni"
    :rules="[rules.required, rules.dni]"
    @input="updateDni($event)"
>
    <div></div>
</v-text-field>
```

y mi metodo es el siguiente:

```
 methods: {
    updateDni(value) {
        this.$emit("input", value);
    }
```

escribi el siguiente test:

```
  it('call updateDni when the input change', async () => {

    const wrapper = shallowMount(InputDni, {   
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    })

    let updateDniSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'updateDni')
    const inputField = wrapper.findComponent({ name: 'v-text-field' })
    inputField.element.value = 'fads'
    await inputField.trigger('input')
    expect(updateDniSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

pero siempre falla indicando que se esperaba que el método sea llamado al menos una vez pero la cantidad de llamadas es cero. Estoy empezando con el tema de test y no se como puedo resolver esto

Comment: Hola, tambien soy nueva en testing y no se mucho, pero que tal si en vez de testear la implementacion (que el metodo updateDni sea llamado) testeas lo que esperas (cual es el resultado de que updateDni sea llamado).

Comment: Hola. Si, eso también lo testeo. Cuando llamo al metodo verifico que se emita un evento

Comment: Digo en vez de verificar que los eventos se llamen verificar que el resultado de llamar el evento es el esperado ejemplo un test de una funcion suma.

Suma(2, 2) en vez de testear que se llame Suma verificar que despues de llamar Suma el resultado sea 4. 

No es una solucion al problema que tienes y la verdad ni he comenzado a usar jest solo fue algo que lei en el blog de kentdoocs https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details ojala te sirva de algo

Comment: Si. Entiendo pero creo que eso sería más un test para el componente que usa este input ya que el resultado de esa función lo voy a ver ahí. Pero a nivel componente quiero probar que cuando cambia el valor del input em metodo es llamado y el método en si solo lanza un emit no hace nada más.